# Is it possible to pause a YouTube video in an iframe using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I have a slider that I'm making which displays an image for my post, then when you click it, it makes the image be replaced by an `iframe` with a YouTube embed. I want to be able to somehow pause the videos using JavScript (or jQuery) by utilizing the iframes ID. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can pause a youtube video.

You can try looking at this code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3J2wT/757/

HTML:

```
<a id="pause" href="#">Pause</a>

<iframe id="popup-youtube-player" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/geTgZcHrXTc?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always">
</iframe>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#pause').on('click', function() {

    $('#popup-youtube-player')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'pauseVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
```

});